# is it possible to customize django 3 admin nav_sidebar menu as a custom group?

Tags: django, nav, sidebar

I'd like to customize the built-in django admin 3 nav left sidebar with my own caption and models list.

The default nav_sidebar is:

```
myapp A
- model A.1
- model A.2

myapp B
- model B.1
- model B.2
```

From my understanding, it's showing all app_list and its models.

I'm wondering if there's any chance to have this following instead?

```
Custom name
- model A.1
- model B.1
```

I'd appreciate any feedback

UPDATE:
I found that I can change the caption (custom name) by assigning the verbose_name in AppConfig.
I still have no idea if I can customize the models list.

Comment: it is not about django. its about bootstrap. check bootstrap docs pls

Comment: Hi @VitAmin, thank you. It's a built-in django nav_side bar. I went to [django repo](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/app_list.html) and saw that the list is from the apps name. So that I'm wondering if there's a way to customize it. instead of showing the existing app name and its models

Comment: I edited my post to make it clear that it's  built-in django nav_sidebar